# Is there a decentralized version of Cloudflare Workers?

Tags: web3-providers, function

Is there a decentralized version of Cloudflare Workers or some comparable service like AWS Lambda functions or GCP Cloud Functions? I would love a blockchain based, or just a decentralized version of a Cloudflare Worker that could run functions called by a static website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fluence](https://fluence.network/) is the only such project that comes to mind at the moment

Comment: Yeah this is a fascinating project, thanks for the resource!